# Does any software exist for Windows XP to change the order of items in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

I know alt + tab is handy, but doing web development on Windows XP can be difficult when I have to open something new, and it's in the far right, and I have Photoshop or something opened in the far left.

As far as I know, there is no way to reorder them natively, but is there something available that can?

Thanks

Comment: If you ever upgrade to Win7, you're going to love it - that's built into the taskbar. Being able to pin software to the taskbar and rearrange them is just one of those little awesome bits that makes Win7 so great to use.

Comment: I'm going to upgrade as soon as I upgrade my machine.

Comment: @alex: no need to wait to upgrade your machine... win7 has about the same performance as xp on the same hardware

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/) and [Taskix](http://taskix.robustit.com/) both do this.

Comment: I've been using this for so long I forgot that I had it installed.  It works so smoothly, you don't even realise that it's there :)

Comment: It comes in very handy, shuffle is my preference.

Comment: Taskix was very buggy when I tried it. Can't live without Taskbar Shuffle though. :)

Comment: Taskbar Shuffle is awesome!

Comment: Taskbar Shuffle works wonderfully for those of us still stuck on XP, and it has a no-install zip version that will work in corporate environments where everything is locked down!

Answer (score -1):

Shift+Alt+Tab will save you in your case. It'll jump to last opened window.

Comment: Actually, no, it will switch to the previously *active* window.  Not at all the same thing as the last window opened.