# How do I re-arrange window order in Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does any software exist for Windows XP to change the order of items in the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/14832/does-any-software-exist-for-windows-xp-to-change-the-order-of-items-in-the-taskba)

I normally keep quite a few windows open and would like to find a utility which allows me to re-arrange my windows from left to right on the taskbar.  I always open an enormous number of apps during the day and it would be nice to be able to move them around on the taskbar.  Anyone have a tool that makes this possible?

Comment: duplicity - http://superuser.com/questions/14832/does-any-software-exist-for-windows-xp-to-change-the-order-of-items-in-the-taskba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [taskbar shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/).  Not only does it help with the reordering left-to-right, but you can also reorder up-and-down in the grouped tasks.