# Reorder windows taskbar items

Tags: windows, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does any software exist for Windows XP to change the order of items in the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/14832/does-any-software-exist-for-windows-xp-to-change-the-order-of-items-in-the-taskba)

Could someone recommend a utility that would allow me to change the order of taskbar items in Windows XP, ideally just by dragging them, similar to reordering tabs in Firefox?

Comment: if you kill explorer.exe from Task Manager, then restart it (or let it restart automatically), it'll reorder the items for you. :)  *(i'm joking.  it does work that way, but be careful if you do this; it can be dangerous.)*

Answer (score 2):

I used to use this program before I upgraded from XP:

[Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/)

> Taskbar Shuffle is a simple, small,
>   free utility that lets you drag and
>   drop your Windows taskbar buttons to
>   rearrange them.  Here’s a full feature
>   list:
>
> - Full 32-bit and 64-bit support
> - Reorder your taskbar buttons by dragging and dropping them
> - Reorder your tray icons in the same way
> - Reorder tasks in a grouped button's popup menu in the same way
> - Middle-click to close programs on your taskbar
> - Works with UltraMon (version 3+ only) taskbars
> - Tweak taskbar button grouping

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Taskix](http://taskix.robustit.com/), which does what I want. It's only a 244KB download and installs without a reboot (which is a rarity for system utilities!)