# Reorder Windows 7 taskbar items

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

It seems like Microsoft goofed up again and did not include a feature in Windows 7 to order taskbar items. To clarify, you can now order the groups, but not the items within the groups.

So let's say I have 10 Windows Explorer taskbar items open and would like to order those taskbar items. What software would I use for Windows 7 to order taskbar items?

Software mentioned in this post "[Does any software exist for Windows XP to change the order of items in the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/14832/does-any-software-exist-for-windows-xp-to-change-the-order-of-items-in-the-taskb)", does not mention Windows 7 support or specifically says that Windows 7 is not supported.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out [7Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

A tool that allows you to:

> - Group/ungroup/show label/hide label per Application ID.
> - Reorder items within a tab group (drag’n'drop).
> - Close/minimize/etc. multiple windows at once.
> - Change Application ID of windows (that is, grouping whatever windows you want). You can open it from the tweaker main window, from its
>     tray menu, or optionally by double/middle clicking the empty space of
>     the taskbar.

Comment: Can i do it without any third software, even change something in registry...?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work! While Firefox is not running on the background and taskbar tweaker is set to launch at windows bootup. I Am on Win 10.